# I have simple questions about drawing and erasing lines in quartz framework

Tags: objective-c, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I am trying to draw and erase lines by quartz framework.

But I'm facing some problems.

Please advice.

**Q1) I have made follow method and excute the method if press UIButton.**

```
- (void)drawCustom {

    cgc_Context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(cgc_Context, 5.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(cgc_Context, [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(cgc_Context, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(cgc_Context, 200, 50);
    CGContextStrokePath(cgc_Context);
}
```

But result I've got is :

> suckjuui-iMac.local QuartzTest[5008] :
> CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0 Jul 20 20:22:50
>
> suckjuui-iMac.local QuartzTest[5008] :
> CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0 Jul 20 20:22:50
>
> suckjuui-iMac.local QuartzTest[5008] : CGContextMoveToPoint:
> invalid context 0x0 Jul 20 20:22:50
>
> suckjuui-iMac.local QuartzTest[5008] : CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0
> Jul 20 20:22:50
>
> suckjuui-iMac.local QuartzTest[5008] :
> CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0

Why does message occur like above?

**Q2) How to erase lines drawn?**

Comment: Please change the title of this question from being totally general  to what your question is specifically about (lines, buttons, drawing., context invalid, ..). This makes it easier to attract people who can actually answer it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for taking advice--which seems to be a rare trait these days :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second question.

You can't erase lines, because as per wattson12 your drawing needs to occur in drawRect.  You can only re-draw the graphics (minus what you wanted to erase).

Answer (score 0):

for the first problem:

UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext returns nil if you aren't calling it from inside drawRect:

move this code into the drawRect method of a custom UIView subclass